# minimum version android development API

Tags: android, google-play

Google says that, since November, the minimum version of the API for publication on the Play Store is 26.
is it not possible to develop for the 21st? old smartphones how will they do?

Answer (score 3):

The minimum *target* SDK version is 26, not the minimum *min* SDK version.

You can still set your minimum as low as 14, the requirement for targeting API 26.

Comment: mmm. something is wrong with my xamarin.forms project. if I set the target version 'same SDK for compilation' (8.1), google play console report error..not accept ...